# Bind result of ASK query in sparql

Tags: sparql

I'm in the process of learning sparql and I'm currently working on a select query where I want to bind the result of a ASK query to the object variable.

The ASK query is working on it's own, but I'm having trouble using the query inside another query.

This is the ASK query:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://domain.com/app/schema/>

ASK { GRAPH <http://domain.com/app/data/something> {

     ?s schema:code "ANS"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
     schema:someid "12345678"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
     schema:startdate ?startdate .

     OPTIONAL { ?s schema:enddate ?enddate }
     BIND(IF(BOUND(?enddate), ?enddate, now()) AS ?resultdate)
     FILTER(?resultdate >= now() && ?startdate < now())
     }
}
```

This returns true or false depending on the the id.

What I would like now is a query that returns two columns like this:

```
+----------+--------+
|    ID    | STATUS |
+----------+--------+
| 12345678 | true   |
| 87654321 | false  |
+----------+--------+
```

I did some attempts, but I can't produce a query with valid syntax:

```
PREFIX schema2: <http://domain.com/app2/schema/>
PREFIX schema: <http://domain.com/app/schema/>

select ?s ?p ?o 
where 
{ GRAPH <http://http://domain.com/app2/data/something>
{?s ?p ?o } .

BIND() {
    ASK { GRAPH <http://domain.com/app/data/something> {

    ?s schema:code "ANS"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
    schema:someid "12345678"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
    schema:startdate ?startdate .

    OPTIONAL { ?s schema:enddate ?enddate }
    BIND(IF(BOUND(?enddate), ?enddate, now()) AS ?resultdate)
    FILTER(?resultdate >= now() && ?startdate < now())
    }
}
}

FILTER(?s = <http://domain.com/app2/data/something/100024>)
}
```

Any advice/examples of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `BIND` with an expression and but not with a query form (`SELECT`, `ASK`, etc).

What you can do is replace `ASK` with an `exists` pattern. Something like this

```
PREFIX schema2: <http://domain.com/app2/schema/>
PREFIX schema: <http://domain.com/app/schema/>

select ?id ?status
where 
{ 
   GRAPH <http://http://domain.com/app2/data/something>
   { 
      ?s schema:someid ?id ;
   }

   BIND( exists 
   {
      GRAPH <http://domain.com/app/data/something> 
      {
         ?s schema:code "ANS"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ;
            schema:startdate ?startdate .

         OPTIONAL { ?s schema:enddate ?enddate }
         BIND(IF(BOUND(?enddate), ?enddate, now()) AS ?resultdate)
         FILTER(?resultdate >= now() && ?startdate < now())
      }
   } as ?status)
}
```

Comment: This is great! Didn't know about the EXISTS operator. Thanks!